# Atualizar e Inserir dados numa tabela com informações de outra em outro banco

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho a seguinte situação:

Banco **A** e o banco **B** ambos com a tabela **clientes** com o os seguintes dados:

```
A.clientes                    B.clientes

id    | nome                  id    | nome
-------------------           -------------------
1     | Lucas                 1     | Mauro
5     | Marcos                3     | Sergio
8     | Paulo
```

Gostaria de um comando para atualizar e inserir na tabela clientes do banco **B** os dados que estivessem na tabela clientes do banco **A** e que esse fosse o resultado:

```
B.clientes
id    | nome
-------------------
1     | Lucas    <- UPDATE
3     | Sergio   
5     | Marcos   <- INSERT
8     | Paulo    <- INSERT
```

Meu SGDB é o PostgreSQL.

Comment: Esses bancos estão no mesmo servidor ou em servidores diferentes?

Comment: Mesmo servidor @JefersonAlmeida

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly passei esse mesmo link na minha resposta, caso ele precise realmente fazer isso

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas maneiras de se fazer isso no `PostgreSQL`.
Você pode utilizar o [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-function.html) por exemplo.

```
insert into clientes
select *
from dblink('dbname=postgres hostaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dbname=A user=postgres',
            'select id,nome from clientes')
       as t1(id int,nome text);
```

Com esse comando acima você poderia consultar as informações no outro banco e atualiza-las ou inserir-las conforme sua necessidade.
Caso não saiba como fazer um comando de `insert` ou `update` você pode está verificando isso nesse link do SO [InserOrUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

Comment: Vou testar e digo o resultado, obrigado.

Comment: @LaércioLopes qualquer dúvida ou problema é só avisar